# Track and report on site traffic in bluemix

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, traffic, devops, visitors

I do not see any application available that tracks the site traffic on a bluemix application. I am currently hosting a Node.js app, that people routinely visit. I want to know the number of visitors to my site but I am seeing no easy way to do this. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Bluemix does not provide an out-of-the-box solution that tracks visits to a hosted application. You would need to use a 3rd-party analytics tool, such as Google Analytics, or scour the log files.